# Multiply a series of matrices

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

I have a matrix like below:

```
[0 0 1 1]
[0 0 1 1]
[0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0]
```

I need to divide it into multiple `3x3` matrices starting from top left through right. It's sort of a `3x3` slide across the matrix. In this example, we would have `4` `3x3` matrices like so:

```
    [0 0 1]     [0 1 1]
1 = [0 0 1] 2 = [0 1 1]
    [0 0 0]     [0 0 0]

    [0 0 1]     [0 1 1]
3 = [0 0 0] 4 = [0 0 0]
    [0 0 0]     [0 0 0]
```

I've tried this using `tf.extract_image_patch` and got the 4 matrices, but I'm still not sure how I can do a sort-of running product for these matrices in Tensorflow. Or, better could achieve the running product without having to pre-calculate the separate matrices.

With running product I mean this: I need to multiple above 1-4 matrices element-wise and need to get `1` `3x3` matrix. For example, `1` `&` `2` matrices would be multiplied, the result would be multiplied with matrix `3`, and the result again would be multiplied with matrix `4`.This operation should give me start of the patch(`[[1 1], [1 1]]`) in my original matrix, a matrix like below:

```
       [0 0 1]   
res =  [0 0 0] 
       [0 0 0]
```

Once done, I need to make this operation part of my network, a Tensorflow layer perhaps.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me achieve this. Thanks.

***EDIT***
This seems to be one way to multiply matrices in a list, but I'm still looking for `1)` slice matrices into multiple parts and multiply them in a better way and `2)` to add this as a layer to a network:

```
tf.scan(lambda a, b: tf.multiply(tf.squeeze(a), tf.squeeze(b)), original)
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use tf.nn.conv2d, manipulating a matrix like this is called a convolution

see tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/conv2d

Comment: Yes, I know conv2d, but unfortunately it doesn't exactly do what I need. I need element-wise multiplication _alone_.

Answer (score 0):

You can use numpy array slicing

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 1, 1],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0]])

res = A[:-1, :-1] * A[:-1, 1:] * A[1:, :-1] * A[1:, 1:]
```

and then, perhaps, convert the numpy array to a Tensor object by

```
tf.convert_to_tensor(res)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am relatively new to Tensorflow, please can you tell me how I can add this operation to my TF network, so that it's executed every time during training?